# Is it bad practice to wrap express app within socketio connection?

Tags: node.js, security, express, socket.io

I'm making a webgame, and if I have a route that looks like:

```
app.post('/create_account', (req, res) => {
    var email = req.body.email
    var pass = req.body.pass
    res.json({response: "created"})
})
```

Anyone can post data to mywebsite.com/create_account using postman, or curl or something, and my website will start creating account for them even though they are not even on my webpage.

I found an interesting workaround, and I wanted to know if this is safe, or even a good idea. Basically I wrap my app routes within a socket.io connection:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    app.post('/create_account', (req, res) => {
        //code goes here
    })
})
```

I tested it, and it seems that this way you can only post to /create_account if you are actually connected to the webpage.

What (if any) are the disadvantages to doing this? If this is a bad idea, whats's a better way to prevent people from posting data if they aren't on my site.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use csrf-tokens.

Comment: You can't do it this way.  You are adding a new duplicate `app.post()` handler for every single incoming socket.io connection.  On each request that hits that route, every single one of them will fire and you will have all sorts of duplicates.  You can't do whatever it is you're trying to do this way.

Answer (score 0):

@Ruslan's suggestion about CSRF tokens is sound and probably your best option, wrapping everything in socket.io seems like too much complexity. Here's a library that does that: https://github.com/expressjs/csurf